# Differences between 0(grounded) and z(floating) in CMOS

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, logic-gates, cmos

I have read the previous discussion [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328978/whats-the-difference-between-0-and-high-impedance-or-floating).

However, I still want to know if the exact voltage of the high impedance state can be calculated.

Based on this, I have some questions:

1. Does the leakage current affect hi-z voltage?
2. For Vd = Vs + Vnoise, are 0 and hi-z the same? (V0 = Vgnd + Vnoise = Vnoise = Vhi-z)

Thanks

Comment: Your finger can affect a hi-z's voltage. It's hi-z. In fact, scope the hi-z with your finger touching. If you are inside anything that has mains voltage wiring (likely as the scope is turned on) you are likely to see your mains AC cycles riding on it.

Comment: No, the exact voltage of a high-impedance state can not (in real life) be calculated. You just have to accept that reality.

Answer (score 2):

High Z is high Z, the voltage is determined by the sum of the various leakage currents and impedances to other nets, but it is not exactly well defined and varies with time, temperature, humidity, what else is happening (capacitive coupling can easily toggle a floating input), board contamination and the phase of the Jovian moons.
As a practical matter all you can say it will probably wind up somewhere between the power rails...

For a floating input (Or one fed from a high Z source), noise is superimposed on whatever the DC level happens to settle to.

Seriously, caring about the state of a high Z line in cmos is a 'doctor it hurts when I do this' thing, you will be happier if you don't do it.